# MVC Controller Action Object Parameter Receives Null Values from AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, api, model-view-controller

Using AJAX to send object including array value to MVC Controller action. Breakpoint shows that the Action is reach but the object receiving the string array is null.

Call to Asp.net MVC Web Api call is made using AJAX. Object is created then JSON.Stringify is used. MVC Action parameter object is set to receive values from AJAX call. I've tried [HttpPost] attribute as well as [Route("api/Controller")]. I've also tried, in javascript to store the object within another object. Then used JSON.stringify and then set that as the ajax 'data' parameter.

Javscript Code

```
        //var data = {
        //    Apimethod: null,
        //    Employees: [],
        //    Type: null
        //};
        var data = [];
        //var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "api/{controller}/" + data.Apimethod,
            data: { employees: data }
            //traditional: true
        }).done(function (response) {
            $('#modelmsg').empty();
            $('#modelmsg').append(response);
            return returnguid = response;
        }).fail(function (response) {
            console.log('Error: ' + response);
        });
```

WebApiConfig

````cs
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Name",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{employees}",
                defaults: new { action = "{name}", employees = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

MVC Controller
```c#
[Route("api/{controller}/{employees}")]
        public IHttpActionResult InsertEmployeesIntoRDLTable(EmployeeList employees)
        {
                //Code Here
                return Json(response);
        }
````

Class Object EmployeeList

```cs
    public class EmployeeList
    {
        public string Apimethod { get; set; }
        public string[] Employees { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

**Error Received from http link that is produced by ajax call:** 
No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String[]' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.

Expected Result overall is to receive parameters from AJAX Call. But Object class stays null.

**Update**

Fetch, as shown below, seems to work. Just not exactly sure why.

So I've found that fetch will do the job. I'm not 100% sure why but it does.

```
        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'credentials': 'include'
            },
            body: jsonData
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(response => {
            //code
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            //code
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to stringify the data. Since you have already provided the `dataType: "json"` option, you can directly supply the data as is.

Try this
`data: { employees:data }`

Also, put an `always` method for further troubleshooting.